# Не получается седлать резиновую вёрстку CSS

Tags: css

К примеру есть простейший сайт с блоками, высота которых не известна заранее.

- Header
- ScrollableArea
- Footer

Высота `header` и `footer` должна всегда быть по содержимому
ScrollableArea должна растягиваться на весь экран, а если места не хватает должен появляться скролл.

Я пробовал по разному. Например вот так, но не получается.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  border: unset solid #808080;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: solid 5px red;
}

.scrollArea {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 5px black;
}

.item {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: double 1px black;
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}

h1 {
  border: double 1px black;
  margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<body style="padding:0px;margin:0px" class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div id="scroll" class="scrollArea">
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 1</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 2</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Добавлено */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: solid 5px red;
}


/* Добавлено */
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrollArea {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  
  /* Добавлено */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: double 1px black;
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}

h1 {
  border: double 1px black;
  margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<body style="padding:0px;margin:0px" class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div id="scroll" class="scrollArea">
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 1</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 2</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 2</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 2</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 2</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>item.Status</p>
        <pre>проба 2</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно.